# Waiting for both YouTubePlayerAPI and JQuery Document to be ready

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api, document-ready

I seem to have a race condition in my code. I am loading the youtube player api asynchronously via:

```
  <script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  </script>
```

And using coffeescript I have:

```
$ ->
  window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = () ->
    #use the youtube player api
```

Sometimes the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()` method fires before the JQuery document ready method and in that case none of the youtube player code runs. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions for handling this?

Comment: How are the youtube videos inserted into the page, statically in the page HTML or dynamically using JS when the page loads?

Comment: @AnthonyBlackshaw They are inserted dynamically using page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on feedback (including example code) from the OP (@wuliwong) the following solution resolves the race condition original hinted at in the OP's question:

```
$(document).bind 'custom-ready', () -> 

    ... custom initialization code ...


# Ensure the 'custom-ready' is called only when both the document and the 
# YouTube player API are ready. As the order this will occur in is not 
# guarenteed the following code caters for both scenarios.

# Cater for the document ready first scenario
$ -> 
    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = () -> 
        $(document).trigger('custom-ready') 

# Cater for YouTube player API ready first scenario
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = () -> 
    $ -> 
        $(document).trigger('custom-ready')
```

*MY ORIGINAL ANSWER (for context):*

I've had what appeared to be the same issue in the past but with a slightly different setup, in my case I was loading `//www.youtube.com/iframe_api`.

In that scenario I was able to move the code that specifically relied on the youtube player API being ready into the `window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` callback and used a standard `<script>` include after, for example:

```
... script tags for non-youtube reliant code ...
<script src="...jquery, plugins, site js..."></script>

... youtube specific code followed by youtube api script tag...
<script>
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        $('.video-gallery').Gallery();
    }
</script>
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

However, I believe another option would be to trigger a custom event for the ready state, for example *(in CoffeeScript)*:

```
$(document).bind 'custom-ready', () -> 
    ... code previously in ready event callback ...

$ ->

    # Check if the page includes the youtube player api (this could be
    # achieved in any number of ways, here we assume a CSS class is 
    # applied to the page body as an indicator.
    if $('body.uses-youtube-player-api').length == 0

        # This page doesn't use the youtube player api so call the
        # custom ready event now.
        $(document).trigger('custom-ready')

# If the page does load the youtube player api trigger our custom
# ready event in the associated callback.
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = () ->
    $(document).trigger('custom-ready')
```

I haven't tested the above example and so it's really only a suggestion since I imagine my original example of how I've previously resolved the issue isn't ideal in many cases.

Remembering back I believe the issue appeared to be caused when the youtube player api code was cached by the browser. To prove that to be the case you could use a random string to load the api player (e.g prefixing a `?_ignore={insert random value}` to the `script` tags `src` attribute) and see if this resolves the issue, however even if it does it wouldn't be an efficient solution for the user as it would require the library to be reloaded every visit.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. I'll test it out in the next couple days. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I didn't implement this exactly but you put me on the final path. If you would like to update with the solution, I'll check your answer.

Comment: Here's my solution. Basically, I setup two different ways that the customReady() method can load. They are exclusive, so if one way occurs the other one necessarily doesn't occur. It is nasty stuff but it works.  `$ ->
  window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = () ->
    $(document).trigger('load-muusical-player')
####line break#######
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = () ->
  $ ->
    $(document).trigger('load-muusical-player')
####line-break#######
$(document).bind 'load-muusical-player', () -> #custom-init-logic-goes-here`   Hopefully it is clear without the line breaks.

Comment: @wuliwong - Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question as per your suggestion. I'm certain your update will come in handy for me too in the future.